# Item not reaching pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to python and `scrapy`. I am not getting item data in pipeline. Nothing is being written in `csv`. Error is

> DmozSpider' object has no attribute **getitem**

Any help will be appreciated:

spider file

```
import scrapy
import sys
import os
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem
from pprint import pprint
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.xyz.co.id"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.xyz.co.id/search?q=abc"]

    def parse(self, response):
        var = response.xpath("//a[@class='img']/@href").extract()[0]
        item = TutorialItem()
        item['title'] = var
        yield item
```

pipeline file

```
import csv

class TutorialPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('items.csv', 'wb'))

    def process_item(self, domain, item):
        print item['title']
        self.csvwriter.writerow([item['title']])
        return item
```

items file

```
import scrapy

class TutorialItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
```

Settings file

```
         ITEM_PIPELINES = {
       'tutorial.pipelines.TutorialPipeline': 300,
   }
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of your pipeline method `process_item()` is incorrect. The bug is in the stated parameters `self, domain, item`. The official description in the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) is:

```
process_item(self, item, spider)
```

Change the method in your class `TutorialPipeline` accrodingly to:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    print item['title']
    self.csvwriter.writerow([item['title']])
    return item
```

Answer (score 0):

Try item.get('title') instead of item['title']